# Star pattern practicing on alignment control

Tags: c

I am practicing to generate the star in the following result, but I was fail.

1.

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

2.

```
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
```

For my logic on this case, I am thinking that could be generated by using width alignment control on the loop, but the result shown that it is wrong...

```
*    *    *    *    *
*    *    *    *
*    *    *
*    *
*
```

With the code:

```
    int i,j;
    char ch='*';//created for using of alignment
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for(j=5;j>=i;j--)
        {
            printf("%5c", ch);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

For my logic, I assume that could be generated by using the method of alignment (%5c).
However, the result is not as same as what I expected.

I have already succeeded to generate the star as shown as below:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

With Code:

```
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for(j=5;j>=i;j--)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Do I have the wrong thinking on the method to make pattern 1 and 2?
Or the right thinking with the wrong coding?

Comment: @VishalSuthar Why does that matter?

Comment: @meagar: Because it is best to guide a student to the correct answer while omitting a complete solution in code.

Comment: @EdS., Not anymore, really. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @chris: That's irrelevant.  You're talking about a tag, I'm talking about how one should approach answering a question asked by a student.  I couldn't care less about the tag, do you think it's good to hand a student something they can turn in?

Comment: @EdS., Yes, but it's mentioned in there that SO is no longer the place for localized homework. If the question is formed in such a way that it will be useful beyond a homework assignment, that's grounds for a good solution.

Comment: @chris: Ok, well I don't particularly care what their opinion is either.  If I know I am answering a question which stems from a homework assignment I'm just not going to post a fully coded solution.  Others are free to do as they see fit, but I don't think it's a good idea.  It may not help them learn how to solve problems themselves and you may just be doing their homework for them.

Comment: @EdS., Indeed. That's where the debate really comes in. I'm opposed to giving out answers to homework questions with no real effort or learning on the asker's side. At least the ones that are somewhat like a copy-paste of the assignment are now typically too localized, and generalizing it typically shouldn't produce an answer that applies directly to the homework at hand, but one that the asker can use to solve that problem and then apply it to their situation like any future visitor would.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for educating students. The status/motives of the asker should have absolutely no bearing on how you answer their question. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to help *future users*, and future users don't want "hints" or "gentle pushes in the right direction". If you don't feel this question should be answered, vote to close it. Do *not* post a partial solution or intentionally withhold information. This is directly at odds with the stated purpose of this site.

Comment: @meagar: Ultimately, SO is what we make it.  For my part, I will continue to approach homework questions differently.  I will still provide a comprehensive, explanatory answer, it just won't contain a complete solution in code. If future visitors can't be bothered to understand a problem and write their own code then I can't say I feel overly sorry for them.

Comment: Even more important: don't derail people's questions with off-topic discussions! Take this to meta.stackoverflow.com or remain silent.

Comment: I am sorry to bring you all so much trouble right here. Actually I am just learning it by self-learning of objective C, and not a student from the school. I apology for the misunderstanding to yours and really appreciate for the kindness from everyone. I understand your kindness, and will not ask this kind of question anymore.

Comment: @Troy: No no no, there's nothing wrong with your question.  Actually, you did exactly what you are supposed to do. You showed that you have already given the assignment an honest attempt and also gave us a good problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To align, you might be actually drawing a rectangle. In each row, you output a series of asterisks (possibly empty, i.e., zero asterisks) and a series of spaces (possibly empty, i.e., no spaces).

It is an ideal application of the `(condition) ? (value_if_true) : (value_if_false)` construct. You *always* draw the full rectangle, and pattern only changes due to condition: "is this a space or an asterisk?"

```
int i, j;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
    {
        // This generates a full rectangle
        // printf("%c", '*');
        // This generates an empty rectangle ;-)
        // printf("%c", ' ');
        // This generates a triangle
        printf("%c", (i >= j) ? '*' : ' ');
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

There are two triangles oriented top-down governed by the condition (i >= j) or (i <= j); to flip the triangles horizontally you replace the increasing sequence with a decreasing sequence, i.e., (6-j) instead of (j):

```
   when j is       6-j is
       1              5
       2              4
      ...            ...
       5               1
```

so that the test is `((6-j) <= i)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the theory below for both patterns:

> Assume a triangle consist of one triangle made up of spaces and another made up of stars. In one for-loop, you can make two other for-loops to control both triangles.

Try the method I suggested and if you do not succeed, let me know I will help...

Answer (score 0):

Chirag is not wrong but you do not need three for-loops for this, just two.

Take Chirag's suggestion:

> Assume a triangle consist of one triangle made up of spaces and another made up of stars.

Now, consider each line independently as a number of stars (and spaces) which decrease/increase with respect to the line number.

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("\n%*s", i, " "); // Print i spaces
    for (j = i; j < 5; j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
}
```

This will give you

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

Comment: hi niklas you are absolutely right... but I want him to try himself :). I just shown the way how he can solve the puzzle...

Comment: That is correct, Chirag Desai, I followed the discussion in the comments but I concur with the meta post.

Your edit is correct, @Michael, however I can't accept it (not enough reputation) so we'll have to wait.